# Is there a way to get a list of all the visible properties on a page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, visible

I want to get a list of all the visible properties on a page within the `OnClick()` method of a particular button. Is there a way to do this programmatically in c# within asp.net?

Comment: MVC or WebForms? What do you mean by 'properties'?

Comment: Web forms. Properties meaning asp:Textbox, asp:Label etc.

Comment: iterate through Page.Controls collections and store it in List<Control>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to recursivly itterate all the controls in the page and find the visible ones :

```
List<Control> visibleList = null;
protected void FindVisibleControls(Control parent) 
{
    foreach(Control c in parent.Controls) 
    {
       if (c.Visible)
       {
          visibleList.Add(c);
       }

       if (c.HasControls())
          FindVisibleControls(c);
    }
}
```

**Usage** - In your button click call it like this:

```
protected Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   visibleList = new List<Control>();
   FindVisibleControls(this);
}
```